# DOM avoid preserve whitespaces

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, java-8

Is it any way to avoid preserve whitespaces in DOM (Whichever java library) ?

I have an XML file validated by an XSD schema. By this schema, only `<text>` element contains texts. Another element contains only element nodes. When I edit XML file, for most visibility, I have several types of whitespaces like tab, blank, carriage return,...

How I can to parse my XML (without xslt, only java libraries) without preserve all whitespaces not authorized by schema ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(boolean) suggests there is a setting that "requires the parser to be in validating mode" (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setSchema(javax.xml.validation.Schema)) and then supports ignoring the white space in element only content models.

Here is an example, given the Java code

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);

    Schema schema = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(new File("schema1.xsd"));
    //dbf.setSchema(schema);

    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = db.parse("file1.xml");

    System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().getLength());
```

with a sample file

```
<root>
    <item>a</item>
    <item>b</item>
</root>
```

the number of child nodes output is 5, now when I remove the comment from

```
dbf.setSchema(schema);
```

and have a schema defining element only contents for the `root` element with e.g.

```
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="item" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

the output for the child nodes is only 2.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank for your response. I tested this code and I have 5 childe nodes in the all cases

Comment: I used Netbeans 8.1 and Java 1.8 to run and test the code and it gives the results I stated in my answer. I am not sure why you get a different result, maybe someone else knows that API better and how well it is supported in the different Java versions. You might want to edit your question and state which Java version you are using or need that to work with respectively which one you have used when you get a different result.

Comment: I use Java 8 too.

Comment: That sounds, I am on Windows, when I add `System.out.println("Java version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));` it outputs `Java version: 1.8.0_77`.

Comment: My JV is : `Java version: 1.8.0_66`. I will try with 0_77

Comment: Not working :(
I'm on `windows 7`. I tried jdk_1.8_111 too. Same results :(

Comment: Its ok. I have another impl of DOM in my maven dependancies. thank you